# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Autosizes Incorrectly or Correctly-Only-on-Selection

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn object which serves as a datasource for one of the columns in my gridview.

The code is as follows:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

comboBoxColumn.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnums));
comboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "MyPropertyName";
comboBoxColumn.Name = "My Column Name";

dataGridView.Columns["MyPropertyName"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
//dataGridView.Columns["MyPropertyName"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
//dataGridView.Columns["MyPropertyName"].Width = CalculateColumnWidthFromEnum(typeof(MyEnums));
dataGridView.Columns.Remove(dataGridView.Columns["MyPropertyName"]);
dataGridView.Columns.Insert(1, comboBoxColumn);
```

I am happy with how WinForms displays my enums appropriately and whatnot. However, the words describing my enums will be cut short and only expand if I open the drop down and then leave that control.

I also tried manually setting the width (as shown by the commented-out lines) and that had no effect

I have two columns like this in my grid view.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Which other `DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode`s have you tried? Also I think the reason your commented statements don't work is the fact that you use the autosizemode. You can't override it...

Comment: All of them. Same behavior is exhibited in each. I set the 'AutoSizeMode' to 'None' when using the commented statements.

Comment: What happens if you omit line 7 and 8, and use 9 instead?

Comment: Well it has to have one of the modes in use. It can't be null.

Comment: Okay, so what with autosize none and calculateFromEnum? Sorry that I'm just taking guesses but I don't know what you've tried and I don't see what could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the approach all wrong.

I was adjusting the width of a column I removed

```
dataGridView.Columns.Remove(dataGridView.Columns["MyPropertyName"]);
```

Instead I should have set the column width using the `comboBoxColumn` as such:

```
comboBoxColumn.Width = whateverWidthIwant;
```

Thanks for everyone's help!